# How can i boost a field dynamically at index time using solrnet

Tags: solrnet

Currently for index time field boosting i am using mapping attribute and giving a static boost like below.

```
[SolrUniqueKey("StudentID")]
 public int JobseekerID { get; set; }
[SolrField("FName")]
 public string FName { get; set; }
[SolrField("LName")]
 public string LName { get; set; }
[SolrField("Subject"),Boost=50]
 public string Subject { get; set; }
[SolrField("SubjectRating")]
 public string SubjectRating { get; set; }
```

Is there a way i can give the boost dynamically ?

For example I will calculate the boost according to SubjectRating and apply that value to boost the subject field ?

Or using reflection i have to change the attribute value ?

Please guide me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/solrnet/u0W3-JxSH5I/discussion

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this link from the SolrNet group:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/solrnet/u0W3-JxSH5I/discussion

Wha tI will suggest from that article is to try and replace the default ISolrDocumentSerializer with your one that you build yourself.

A bit hard but there are not many other options I can think of.